# How to do not override but combine new box-shadows rule over a previously applied one?

Tags: css

The boostrap button has a shadow for focus, acvite or highlight state.
This display indication of selectio is very important.

[image]

I would like to add another 'box-shadow' into the button like this:

[image]

the rule is `box-shadow: inset 0px -6px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);`

however when i apply this rule to the butotn, all other box-shadow settings are overriden by this 'new rule'. in this case i lost the highlight effect.

How can i combine two box-shadows applying a new but without override the previous one.

PS I alredy know solutions like adding a inside or wrapper div or adding the style to ::after or ::before. Im looking for a solution to apply new shadows without overriding the previous one

Comment: can you create a working code version of your issue?.

Comment: The question you are asking doesn't seem to be reflected to what you are trying to achieve...it sounds like you just need find a away apply new style to a specific button, not all buttons, therefore, you'd need add some identification to that specific button that would be different from the rest. Otherwise you question sounds like you want apply both old and new style at the same time.